# What is the best way to GET two index requests from the same model in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a WorkSpace model that has_many reviews.
In the reviews model I have a rating column using integers for a numbered rating.

I would like to list all of the `work_spaces` from a WorkSpace model and also list the top 5 `work_spaces` based on the overall review rating of the models.

In my controller I have an index method that works well for retrieving all of the work_spaces.

WorkSpacesController

```
# GET /work_spaces
  def index
    @work_spaces = WorkSpace.all

    render json: @work_spaces
  end
```

I have been successful in retrieving the top rated work_spaces by placing my logic in my work_space model.

WorkSpace

```
class WorkSpace < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :delete_all
  acts_as_votable

  scope :by_average_for, ->(column) {
    joins(:reviews)
      .group('work_spaces.id')
      .order("AVG(reviews.#{column}) desc")
      .having("AVG(reviews.#{column}) > 4", column) if column
  }

  def top_avg_rating
    WorkSpace.by_average_for(:rating).limit(5)
  end
```

I send this info out through my serializer and it's easily accessible, but it's attached to every work_space that's indexed. I don't need to have the info attached to each and every work_space. I would ultimately only need to GET this info when the application initially loads.

I figured it would be easy enough to just run a GET request for that info in the WorkSpaces Controller, so I tried adding this method to the controller.

WorkSpacesController

```
  def top_rated
    @work_spaces = WorkSpace.by_average_for(:rating).limit(5)

    render json: @work_spaces
  end
```

I tried to write a new route for it, but I had trouble figuring out how to do that. I tried this in my routes.

```
get 'top_rated', to: 'work_spaces#top_rated'
```

with my path being `http://localhost:4741/work_spaces/top_rated`

This responded with:

> Started GET "/work_spaces/top_rated" for ::1 at 2020-04-26 23:35:38 -0400
>   Processing by WorkSpacesController#show as */*
>     Parameters: {"id"=>"top_rated"}
>     User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["token", "3bbddce2b4c8f7e6a79a62f56ad9229a"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>     WorkSpace Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "work_spaces".* FROM "work_spaces" WHERE "work_spaces"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>   [active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.06ms)
>   Completed 404 Not Found in 16ms (Views: 2.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)

This seems to me that the parameters are looking for an ID for showing a work_space.

I replaced my original index method with the top_rated method and that worked well, but I can't seem to get both indexes working at the same time.

Should I just leave the logic in the model? I'm wondering what the best practice is for this type of logic. Thanks in advance for any help or guidance you can give me.

**Update**

I got this to work thanks to [NemyaNation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3396971/nemyanation).

I changed my route in routes.rb to `get '/work_spaces/top_rated' => 'work_spaces#top_rated'`

This didn't work until I moved the route above some of my other routes.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :reviews, except: %i[new edit]
  get '/work_spaces/top_rated' => 'work_spaces#top_rated'
  resources :work_spaces, except: %i[new edit]
  # RESTful routes
  resources :examples, except: %i[new edit]
  resources :work_spaces do
    member do
      put 'like', to: 'work_spaces#upvote'
      put 'unlike', to: 'work_spaces#downvote'
      get 'likes', to: 'work_spaces#like'
    end
  end

  # Custom routes
  post '/sign-up' => 'users#signup'
  post '/sign-in' => 'users#signin'
  delete '/sign-out' => 'users#signout'
  patch '/change-password' => 'users#changepw'
  patch '/update-user' => 'users#update'
end
```

Not 100% sure why that is... but using the `rake routes` to check my available routes was extremely helpful and led me to hunt down a better understanding of routes.

A couple of links I found helpful:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

https://devhints.io/rails-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path to the top_rated definition is wrong.

Change your routes.rb to show:

```
get 'work_spaces/top_rated', to: 'work_spaces#top_rated'
```

Use the command `rake routes` to show you how to properly construct your routes.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I adjusted my routes.rb to match your answer, but I was still receiving the same message. I moved the route up a few lines in the code and now it works. I'll post updated code in my question.

Comment: Of course!! Thanks again. The `rake routes` rabbit hole was very useful to go down. I learned a lot, mostly that I have a lot to learn!